# How to remove this JavaScript null error?

Tags: javascript

I'm using the following to create an if statement based on the last word of the url after the slash:

```
  // Sticky

  var match = location.search.match(/(\w+)$/)[0];

  if (match === 'complete') {
    $('p:has(audio)').addClass('sticky-child');
    $('p:has(audio)').appendTo('.lesson_lang_switch');
  }
```

The problem is, the front page doesn't have any word at the end of the URL (After the slash):

> www.example.com/

So I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
```

How  can I do it so that the error doesn't appear?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could add a conditional check. i.e.

```
var match = (location.search.match(/(\w+)$/)) 
    ? location.search.match(/(\w+)$/)[0] 
    : "";

 if (match === 'complete') { // match will be "" if the above is false
    $('p:has(audio)').addClass('sticky-child');
    $('p:has(audio)').appendTo('.lesson_lang_switch');
 }
```

Comment: Well this is not the most efficient way to do it. You are now doing the regular expression twice. Well you can do it just once.

Comment: True, however the browser will cache the result, so its not quite the same as doing two separate regex tests. I guess in reality you'd need to know if the results should fail more frequently then it passes

Comment: Does it cache it? Do you have any prove for that?

Comment: The browser caches collections in the background. It's something I leaned from SO a while ago. I'll dig it out (modern browsers that is)

Comment: So I was slightly mistaken, the caching is the browsers selector engine, not necessarily the calculations, however [this jspef](http://jsperf.com/regex-cache-repeated) does seem to show that doing the same regex again is faster the second time round, so maybe a similar function is being used.

Answer (score 4):

You can check if the value is `null`:

```
 // Sticky
 var loc = "www.example.com/";
 var match = loc.match(/(\w+)$/) === null ? "" : loc.match(/(\w+)$/)[0];

 if (match === 'complete') {
     $('p:has(audio)').addClass('sticky-child');
     $('p:has(audio)').appendTo('.lesson_lang_switch');
 }
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3n1qerL9/)

Answer (score 3):

You have to check if the search actually exists. You might want to do something like this:

```
var match = location.search ? location.search.match(/(\w+)$/)[0] : undefined;

if (match === 'complete') {
    $('p:has(audio)').addClass('sticky-child');
    $('p:has(audio)').appendTo('.lesson_lang_switch');
}
```

`location.search ?` will return true if there is a value inside `location.search` if it does then the regular expression will be done. Else it will get the value undefined.

The reason you got this error is because `location.search` did not had any value. The regular expression returns `null`. And because you are trying to read `[0]` from `null` you will get this error.

Answer (score 2):

you could check if there is something found like this:

```
var match = location.search.match(/(\w+)$/);
  if(match != null){
    match = match[0];
    if (match === 'complete') {
      $('p:has(audio)').addClass('sticky-child');
      $('p:has(audio)').appendTo('.lesson_lang_switch');
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

string.match returns an Array containing the matched results or **null** if there were no matches. With this being said, I suggest that you check to see what location.search.match returns before attempting to apply and index to it.

Example:

```
var matches = location.search.match(/(\w+)$/);

if(matches){
    var match = matches[0];
    if (match === 'complete') {
        $('p:has(audio)').addClass('sticky-child');
        $('p:has(audio)').appendTo('.lesson_lang_switch');
    }
}
```

Please see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) if you want to learn more about JavaScript's string.match method.